# Number in for loop doesn't increment

Tags: c

I got the task to scan 10 numbers that will later on be converted into characters. The problem is that I don't get why there is an infinite loop if I don't enter 0. I got the task right with array but I am interested why does this happen in example bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
/**
* for the example enter numbers: 8 5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12 4 -> helloworld
*/
    char n;
    // message needs to be 10 numbers long.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      // enter message in numbers.
        scanf("%d", &n);
        // check if it is 0. if it is, end the message.
        if(n == 0) {
            printf("\nEnd of the message!");
            break;
        // if number is not 0, add 64 to transform to char.
        }else {
            n = n + 64;
            // print the char.
            printf("%c ", n);
            // print the i, that doesn't increment.
            printf(" -> i:%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using that did not warn about  `char n; ...  scanf("%d", &n);`?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (repl.it and Code::Blocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using

```
char n;
...
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You cannot use `%d` with `char`.  You should change `n` to an `int` or use `%c` for `scanf` and `printf`.

```
int n;
...
scanf("%d", &n);
```

OR

```
char n;
...
scanf("%c", &n);
```

Comment: thank you. it worked now. noob mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `char` to read an `int`. The `scanf` fails and input remains in the buffer and so `scanf` keeps on reading the same value again and again resulting in an infinite loop.

So, declare `n` as an `int`.

**It is a good practice to check the return value of `scanf` so that you will know if the input has been read properly**.

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, **the function returns the number of input items assigned**, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the scan!

`scanf("%c", &n);`

`%d` for ints, `%c` for chars, `%s` for strings, `%f` for floats!

Comment: `%d` for **d**ecimal whole numbers ;)

Comment: Wops, thanks for that! Decimal integers 0-9! [scanf cplusplus!](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)! @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d", &n)` reads an **int** into n. Since n is a char this results in the 3 bytes that appear after n being overwritten by the scanf. In your case the variable `i` was allocated within memory that overlaps those 3 bytes and so each call to `scanf` modifies the variable `i` resulting in a potentially infinite loop. Use `%c` to read in a character rather than `%d`.